# Image processing in shader and export results

Tags: javascript, opengl-es, three.js, webgl, fragment-shader

Is there a good/recommended way to do image processing in the fragment shaders then export the results to an external Javascript structure?

I am currently using a Shaders Texture with THREEJS (WebGL 1.0) to display my data.
It contains an array of 2D textures as uniform. I use it to emulate a 3D texture.

At this point all my data is stored in the Fragment Shader and I want to run some image processing on the whole data (not just the pixels on screen), such as thresholding, then export the results of the segmentation to a proper JS object.

I want to do it in the shaders as it runs so much faster.

Rendering To Texturing would not help in this case (I believe) because I want to modify/update the whole 3D texture, not only what is visible on screen.

I doesn't seem that the Effect Composer from THREEJS is what I am looking for either.

Does it make sense? Am I missing something?

Is there some code/demo/literature available out there on how to do "advanced" imaging processing in the shaders (or better yet with THREEJS Shader Texture), then save out the results?

Best

Answer (score 0):

You can render as usual into the canvas and then use `canvas.getImageData()` to retrieve the image.

Then there is the method `renderer.readRenderTargetPixels()` (see [here](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/dev/src/renderers/WebGLRenderer.js#L2634-L2706)). I haven't used it yet, but it appears to do what you want.

So you can just render as you described (rendering to texture won't overwrite your textures as far as i can tell) into a framebuffer (i.e. using `THREE.WebGLRenderTarget`) and then use that method to retrieve the image-data.

Comment: Hmm that doesn't seem to help - basically I provide a uniform to my shader then I want to update it from the shader itself if possible...

Comment: Unfortunately that will not work. Uniforms (and in fact all non-local variables) are always readonly. The only way to output an image from a shader-computation is by writing it into a framebuffer.